Safari not showing updated svg image on my website unless cache is manually cleared
I am facing an issue where Safari doesn't show my updated svg image, unless the cache is manually cleared. Sadly, it doesn't show any image, not even the old one, just a blank space. I am only having this issue with Safari. When I inspect the element in the browser, it's existing with correct src path. I can open the link to the source in the browser and it's showing the image. But not on the webpage. I have tried with several devices on safari and whenever I clear the cache the image shows up, but I can't expect website visitors to do that.
This is what I've tried so far:

Renaming file
Adding version number to file src="/images/logo.svg?v=1.01"
Meta Tags

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">


.htaccess config

<FilesMatch "\.(svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</FilesMatch>

Some more information:

My website is hosted on a shared hosting service
I am using Safari on iOS 17.4.1 and macOS Safari Version 16.6

Despite these efforts, there is still only a blank space, so I am looking for any advice.
Thank you!

"Adding version number to file src="/images/logo.svg?v=1.01"" - that makes it a different URL, so the browser can't fetch it from cache. (And I would not assume Safari to be "broken" regarding something such fundamental.)

@CBroe Thank you! This helped me realize that the svg wasn't the issue.

I've resolved the issue. Previously, the logo had the style max-width:100% applied to it. This caused that the logo's width collapsed to 0 in Safari.
I updated the css file, and removed that style, but it was cached in Safari and since my focus was primarily on ensuring that the SVG file wasn't cached, I didn't realize that Safari was getting an outdated style.
I solved this by applying a version number to the css file.
